# How to access a network though peering in GCP-AWS vpn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-vpc, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I have the following topology:

- GCP with 2 vpcs: A and B. A is 10.0.0.0/16 and B is 10.1.0.0/16. A has peering with B, so A can access B but B can't access A.
- AWS with a vpc C.

I want to make a VPN between GCP and AWS, so that from C I can access A and B. But When I created the VPN tunnel between C and A, C could only access A. How C could access B through VPN in this case?

Comment: @marcin's answer is correct. If you only need to access systems on the peered network on a specific port, you can use SSH port forwarding (tunneling) to get from AWS C -> A -> B. The instance in A provides the SSH server which does the forwarding. https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example Sounds complicated, but it is very easy to setup. Note for production networking, I would use 2 VPN tunnels. SSH tunneling is great for development and test cases but not for production quality infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPC peerings are **not transitive**. From GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering):

> Only directly peered networks can communicate. **Transitive peering is not supported**.

Same goes for VPN connection in [AWS](https://purple.telstra.com.au/blog/aws-site-to-site-vpn-and-transit-gateway):

> **VPN will only route traffic to the VPC it is connected** to and **VPC peer connections are not ‘transitive’**.

So if you have VPN between C and A, only these can communicate. There is no transitive connection from C to B. Would need to have second VPN from C to B.

Comment: VPC peering supports exchanging custom routes - https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#benefits_of_exchanging_custom_routes

Comment: @AvinoamMeir Thank your for letting me know. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach B through the VPN by using custom routes exchange.
See [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#benefits_of_exchanging_custom_routes)